# El valor de un text-input en HTML me da undefined en Javascript. Como puedo solucionarle, que me de el valor ingresado por el usuario?

Tags: javascript, html

Los pongo en contexto, estoy desarrollando un aplicación web que realiza las operaciones matemáticas necesarias para hacer un subneteo Clase C. Para realizar esto ocupo almacenar el valor ingresado en la entrada de texto correspondiente a la dirección IP y el valor ingresado en la correspondiente a la cantidad de subredes deseadas a crear. Esto anterior con el fin de luego usarlas para hacer todo el trabajo matemático.

**El código HTML:**

Las entradas de texto y los botones que se encargan de ejecutar las funciones en Javascript están enmaquetados de la siguiente manera en HTML:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Subnet Maker
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">Subnet Maker</div>
        <div id="arte">
            <input type="text" placeholder="IP Address" class="textinput" id="t1">
            <input type="button" class="redbutton" id="b1" value="Set">
    
            <input type="text" placeholder="Number of subnets" class="textinput" id="t2">
            <input type="button" class="redbutton" id="b2" value="Set">
            
            <input type="button" class="redbutton" id="b3" value="Display">
        </div>
        <div id="displayer"></div>
        <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**El código Javascript:**

En resumen lo que hace mi script de Javascript es almacenar los `div` de HTML en constantes (`const`), añadir el evento `onclick` a las funciones validadoras (estas validan que la entrada del usuario sea valida, de lo contrario corregirlo). Finalmente hacer un `innerHTML` para los resultados del trabajo matemático. A continuación lo adjunto:

```js
    //Invocación de los 'div' de HTML
    const text1 = document.getElementById("t1");
    const text2 = document.getElementById("t1");
    const displayer = document.getElementById("displayer");
    
    //Variables globales (para no usar argumentos en las funciones)
    var ipaddress;
    var nsubnets;
    
    //Validación de la dirección IP
    function ipvalidator(input) {
        ipaddress = input.value;
    
        if (ipaddress !== '' && String(ipaddress).length < 15 && String(ipaddress).length > 7 && typeof ipaddress === 'number' && ipaddress.match('.').length === 3) {
            return true;
        } else {
            displayer.innerHTML = `Please enter an valid IP Address. ${ipaddress} is not a valid IP Address.`;
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    //Validación de la cantidad de subredes
    function nsubnetsvalidator(input) {
        if (input.value !== '' && input.value < 65 && input.value > 0 && typeof input.value === 'number') {
            nsubnets = input.value; 
            return true;
        } else if (input.value > 65 || input.value < 0) { 
            displayer.innerHTML = `Are you sure want to subnet ${input.value} subnets? Please enter a valid number`;
            return false;
        } else if (input.value !== '' || typeof input.value !== 'number') {
            displayer.innerHTML = `Please only enter integer numbers`;
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    //Ultima validación
    function allValidator() {
        if (ipvalidator(text1) === true && nsubnetsvalidator(text2) === true) {
            displayResult();
        } else {
            displayer.innerHTML = `Something went wrong. Plese enter valid values in the text boxes`
        }
    }
    
    //Resultados por pantalla
    function displayResult() {
        tsubnets = String(nsubnets);
        trange = 256 / nsubnets;
    
        for (let i = 0;i < nsubnets;i = i + 1) {
            displayer.innerHTML = `
            ID: ${tsubnets.slice(tsubnets.length - 1,tsubnets.length)}${(trange * i) - trange}\n
            Broadcast: ${(trange * i) - 1}
            Range: ${((trange * i) - trange) + 1} - ${((trange * i) - 1) - 1}
            `
        }
    }
    
    //Eventos 'onclick' enlazados con las funciones validadoras
    document.getElementById("b1").onclick = ipvalidator;
    document.getElementById("b2").onclick = nsubnetsvalidator;
    document.getElementById("b3").onclick = allValidator;
```

**El gran problema:**

Todo lo ingresado por el usuario el script lo toma como `undefined`. Esto lo sé por que cuando se presionas ciertos botones se deben de mostrar ciertos textos con pantalla que invocan el valor de la variable que almacena el valor de la entrada de texto, y es `undefined`. Además ejecuto las funciones validadoras en la consola de mi navegador (Chrome) y retornan `false`, osea `undefined`.

Por eso mismo me da el error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
```

En resumen, mi problema es que lo que ingresa el usuario en el `input` es `undefined`. No puede usar esos datos.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

```js
//Invocación de los 'div' de HTML
const text1 = document.getElementById("t1");
const text2 = document.getElementById("t1");
const displayer = document.getElementById("displayer");

//Variables globales (para no usar argumentos en las funciones)
var ipaddress;
var nsubnets;

//Validación de la dirección IP
function ipvalidator(input) {
    ipaddress = input.value;

    if (ipaddress !== '' && String(ipaddress).length < 15 && String(ipaddress).length > 7 && typeof ipaddress === 'number' && ipaddress.match('.').length === 3) {
        return true;
    } else {
        displayer.innerHTML = `Please enter an valid IP Address. ${ipaddress} is not a valid IP Address.`;
        return false;
    }
}

//Validación de la cantidad de subredes
function nsubnetsvalidator(input) {
    if (input.value !== '' && input.value < 65 && input.value > 0 && typeof input.value === 'number') {
        nsubnets = input.value; 
        return true;
    } else if (input.value > 65 || input.value < 0) { 
        displayer.innerHTML = `Are you sure want to subnet ${input.value} subnets? Please enter a valid number`;
        return false;
    } else if (input.value !== '' || typeof input.value !== 'number') {
        displayer.innerHTML = `Please only enter integer numbers`;
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//Ultima validación
function allValidator() {
    if (ipvalidator(text1) === true && nsubnetsvalidator(text2) === true) {
        displayResult();
    } else {
        displayer.innerHTML = `Something went wrong. Plese enter valid values in the text boxes`
    }
}

//Resultados por pantalla
function displayResult() {
    tsubnets = String(nsubnets);
    trange = 256 / nsubnets;

    for (let i = 0;i < nsubnets;i = i + 1) {
        displayer.innerHTML = `
        ID: ${tsubnets.slice(tsubnets.length - 1,tsubnets.length)}${(trange * i) - trange}\n
        Broadcast: ${(trange * i) - 1}
        Range: ${((trange * i) - trange) + 1} - ${((trange * i) - 1) - 1}
        `
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Subnet Maker
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">Subnet Maker</div>
    <div id="arte">
        <input type="text" placeholder="IP Address" class="textinput" id="t1">
        <input type="button" class="redbutton" id="b1" value="Set" onclick = "ipvalidator(t1)">

        <input type="number" placeholder="Number of subnets" class="textinput" id="t2">
        <input type="button" class="redbutton" id="b2" value="Set" onclick = "nsubnetsvalidator(t2)">
        
        <input type="button" class="redbutton" id="b3" value="Display" onclick = "allValidator()">
    </div>
    <div id="displayer"></div>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que ocurre es que estas usando el `value` de los botones en vez del el `value` de los `text` asi que le hice unos cambios muy pequeños al codigo, revisa tus funciones de validacion porque no funcionan como deberian.

Los cambios hechos son:

- No se le añaden los eventos desde el código si no desde el html.
- Al momento de añadir los eventos oyentes en el **HTML** nos aseguramos de pasarle como parametro los inputs relevantes y **NO** el propio boton.
- He cambiado el tipo de input text por tipo `number` para el caso de `"Number of subnets"`, puesto que lo he visto mas conveniente, ya que el input tipo number devuelve directamente numeros (tu funcion no reconoce bien esto, por lo que hay que revisar esa validacion que haces).

Comment: Cuales cambios tengo que hacerle a las validaciones?

Comment: Mas tarde edito mi respuesta y coloco eso de manera mas especifica,  pero para empezar cuando usas match deberias usarlo en base a una ReGExp que te devuelva todas las coincidencias,  porque si no usas una Regex match siempre te devuelve solo el primer valor que coincida (por lo tanto muy probablemente tu condicion no se cumpla).